# Access MDB VBA Query not working

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to connect to a access database file in VBA and create a table but i cannot seem to be able to query back the values after I have inserted them. For instance, the query "SELECT * FROM TESTME WHERE 'Portfolio' = 'FALL' is always returning back no records. I have even tried "While NOT RS.EOF" but its always true. Any ideas what's wrong with my syntax? Thanks.

```
Sub CreateTblinDb()
On Error GoTo errhandler:
Dim scon As String
Dim ssql As String

scon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
   "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=" & Jet4x & _
  ";Data Source=" & "C:\a2000.mdb"
'creates a table in the database

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

ssql = "CREATE TABLE TESTME2 ('Portfolio' memo, 'TradeType' memo)"

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

cn.Open scon
cn.Execute ssql

ssql = "INSERT INTO TESTME2 VALUES('FALL','TEST')"
cn.Execute ssql

ssql = "SELECT * FROM TESTME2 WHERE 'Portfolio' = 'FALL'"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open ssql, cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
Debug.Print rs.RecordCount ' ALWAYS RETURNING 0

Exit Sub
```

errhandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub

Answer (score 2):

`'Portfolio'` and `'FALL'` are two different strings and will never equal each other; not even on June 23rd, 2011 at 6:29pm.

What's more, your table definition statement does not look correct for a similar reason.

Edit:
Since backticks are not ANSI SQL, there a couple of other things to try:

1. brackets, or
2. double-quotes.

After you fix the table definition statement you might try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM TESTME2 WHERE [Portfolio] = 'FALL'
```

Edit:
Example DDL by request...

```
CREATE TABLE TESTME2 ([Portfolio] memo, [TradeType] memo)
```

Comment: Ok i mean to refer to the actual 'Portfolo' column. How do i go about doing that?

Comment: Thanks, what's the correct way to define my table definition? Please be mindful that these columns are programmaticaly read in in reality and they may have spaces which is why i need to surround the column name with quotes or is there some other way to do it? Can you show with an example? Many thanks.